# From raw xml (no schema) to c# class?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have an xml file that I would like to generate a c# class for. Is there any quick and easy way to do this? I don't have a schema to go with my xml file, it's just raw xml. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You can generate a schema using Microsoft's XSD Schema creator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All code generation tools that I know will require a schema - but you can easily create one from your XML data file.

You can use `xsd.exe` to infer a XML schema from the XML data file:

```
xsd.exe yourdata.xml
```

This will create a `yourdata.xsd`. Of course, xsd.exe can only be guessing - pretty good sometimes, not so good other times. You might want to check (and possibly modify) the schema before proceeding.

(You can do the same in Visual Studio: load the XML file, and from the XML menu, choose "Create schema").

From that schema, you can then create serializable classes:

```
xsd.exe yourdata.xsd /classes
```

This will create a `yourdata.cs` file that contains a C# class that can be serialized into and deserialized from your XML data files.

Marc